# Load div after iframe is done loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I want to load `pictures.php` inside a div with id `main` after iframe is done loading...

Here's my index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='jquery.min.js' ></script>
<script src='upload.js' ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='main' ><?php include("pictures.php");  ?></div>

<form action='upload.php' target='tar_wp' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' >
<iframe src='' name='tar_wp' width='0' height='0' onload='tar_wp()' ></iframe>

<input type='file' name='pic' id='pic' />
<button type='submit' id='submit' >submit</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my pictures.php:

```
<?php

$img = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
while($rows_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($img)){

    $i_img = $rows_img['image_path'];

}

echo "<img src='$i_img' width='200px' height='200px' />";

?>
```

and upload.php works perfect, it inserts the image I needed, it's just the loading dont work....

I use iframe as a target to avoid loading the whole page instead to load only the div with id `main`...

and here's my upload.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function{

        var pic = $("#pic").val();

        if(pic == ""){

            $("#pic").focus();

        }
        else{

             $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             success: function () {

                    $("#main").load("index.php"); // load div to see changes after uploading

                  }
             });

        }

    });

});
```

unfortunately, it doesn't load the div to see new uploads. I have to refresh the whole page to see new uploads. I've also tried this code on iframe `onload` event:

```
function tar_wp(){

    $("#main",window.parent.document).load("pictures.php");

}
```

Any idea is highly appreciated, Thanks in advance....

BTW my main goal is to load pictures.php inside the div with id `main` after the iframe is done loading...

Comment: i think tar_wp is in your parent document but inside the function your trying to apply parent dpocuments functions...

Answer (score 0):

on success function you can load your page like this

```
success: function () {
   $('#main').load('picture.php');
}
```